# download all files on a server but only files access no root access

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, curl, download, wget

So i want to download all files from this site https://blablabla.com/storage/files/*.pdf

" * " is a number e.g. "93028938" and sometimes "im83939883" and website directly cannot be accessed like https://blablabla.com or it's sub directory https://blablabla.com/storage/
no captcha or restrictions are there
files are in sequence 1 to 99999999 and im1 to im99999999

i tried

wget -r -l0 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.pdf -erobots=off https://blablabla.com/storage/files/

but no success please help